# Manage "Properties" tab on PCF code component in Canvas PowerApp

Tags: reactjs, typescript, powerapps

I have a React application which is represent PCF control.
I have configured all properties in XML config and those properties appearing on `Advanced` tab and do not appear on `Properties` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/manifest-schema-reference/property).

How can I add then also to `Properties` and configure their controls (e.g. use them as color picker, etc.) See pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there is no option for that in current PCF release. Only inline options in `Advanced` tab could be used for customization and configuration.